# Overloading operator-= without a class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload `-=` like this without it being a method of a class?

```
vector<int>& operator-=(int a, int b){
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(a); v.push_back(b);
    return v
}
```

I have a line in a homework assignment that looks something like this:

```
SomeStructure-=1-=2-=3;
```

What it is supposed to do is remove the elements with the indexes 1, 2 and 3 from the structure(in that order).

It seems like the option I tried above is not possible (I was thinking of collecting all the indexes in a vector and then removing them from the structure one by one). Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Can you overload by return type??????

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: I suspect you want something more like: `SomeStructure& operator-=(SomeStructure& s, int index);`

Comment: it's not up to me. I didn't choose to write it like this. out instructor did and I'm supposed to make it work somehow

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581961/c-how-to-overload-operator

Comment: What @40two means is that according to your question, it looks that you can don for instance a-=b (with a and b int) and  return something which is not int. Because of that, the first type of the two arguments (a) has to be the same type as the return type. How else would you distinguish between returning an int or a vector?

Comment: Plus in the code you posted you're returning a local object (i.e., `vector<int> v`) by reference. That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: It looks like an odd question to me, confusing two distinct issues as it does.  This is your instructor's first time teaching this course, isn't it?

Comment: no, but he has a habit of not thinking things through when he writes the assignments and then it's up to us to find his mistakes

Answer (score 4):

The assignment operator is right to left associative.

From the C++ Standard

> 5.17 Assignment and compound assignment operators [expr.ass]
>
> 1 The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators
>   all group right-to-left.

So this expression

```
SomeStructure-=1-=2-=3;
```

is in any case invalid because you may not write

```
2 -= 3;
```

And you may not overload operators for built-in types.

I advice to write simply a function for example with name erase which will have parameter of type `std::initializer_list` In this case you could write

```
SomeStructure.erase( { 1, 2, 3 } );
```

Comment: wait, but Piotr above says it is valid since `-=` has left associativity

Comment: @littlerunaway: Piotr was wrong.  Standard actually says "The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left."

Comment: so there's no way to make it work the way it's written now? because i can't change it

Comment: @littlerunaway: Your question says the line is "something like" that.  What is it exactly?  Details could make a difference.

Comment: no, it's exactly that actually. just the structure type is something I didn't want to specify

Comment: I understand there are better ways to do this, but it's not up to me

Comment: @littlerunaway: We could perhaps make `some -= 1st -= 2nd -= 3rd;` work using user-defined literals... but the syntax you have now is quite impossible, since `-=` appears with two operands of built-in type, and you can't override that.

Answer (score 1):

When overloading an operator, at least one of the types passed as parameter has to be a `non primitive type`, which is not your case, that's why we usually overload operators `inside classes` and more rarely as `global functions`.