# is there a way to copy behavior of a function into another in C++?

Tags: c++, function

```
struct Vec{
    int x;
    int y;
    Vec operator+(const Vec &v){
        x+=v.x;     y+=v.y;
        return *this;
    }
    Vec Vec::operator+=(const Vec &v){
        x+=v.x;     y+=v.y;
        return *this;
    }
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Vec &v){
    return out << "x : " << v.x << "\ny : " << v.y << "\n";
}
```

my + and += operator have same behavior how can I avoid redefinition?

Comment: See the *Binary arithmetic operators* section of the top answer.

Comment: `operator+=` should be returning a reference to `this`, i.e. `Vec&`, not a brand new `Vec`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: For that matter, `operator+` should be `const`, i.e. shouldn't be modifying `this` (it's returning a copy, but it's a copy of the mutated original object).

Comment: You cannot avoid defining both functions. You can call a common implementation function from both to reduce duplication. As for the signature of +=, check out this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581961/c-how-to-overload-operator

Comment: @GonenI: Typically, the "common implementation function" *is* `operator+=`, where `operator+` is implemented in terms of it (as NathanOliver mentioned, it's under *Binary arithmetic operators* on [this answer to the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/364696)), you don't implement a third function at all (unless perhaps you're in a situation where that third function could form the common implementation for 3+ the mathematical operators by having many operator overloads call it with the `<functional>` functors (e.g. `std::plus`, `std::minus`, etc.).